# Why am I getting undefined method 'save' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My code is this

```
def footstamp
    if current_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @tracking = Tracking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :target_user_id => @user.id)

        if @tracking
            @tracking.accessed_at = Time.now
            @tracking.save          
        else
            @tracking = Tracking.new
            @tracking.user_id = current_user.id
            @tracking.target_user_id = @user.id
            @tracking.accessed_at = Time.now
            @tracking.save          
        end
    end     
end
```

Then I get this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
@tracking = Tracking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :target_user_id => @user.id).first
```

Comment: I will for sure. It says wait for 6 more mins:)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the result of your method do not return a `Tracking`, but an array of `Trackings`.

Either you introduce more conditions to match only one `Tracking`, or use the `first` method or iterate over the results,

To use first:

```
@tracking = Tracking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :target_user_id => @user.id).first
```

Iterate:

```
Tracking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :target_user_id => @user.id).each do |tracking|
        if tracking
            tracking.accessed_at = Time.now
            tracking.save          
        else
            tracking = Tracking.new
            tracking.user_id = current_user.id
            tracking.target_user_id = @user.id
            tracking.accessed_at = Time.now
            tracking.save          
        end
end
```

Comment: Thanks:) But this time I'll give a credit to Aman since he posted right answer first. Thanks anyway, though!

Answer (score 0):

Optimised answer,

```
def footstamp
    if current_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @tracking = Tracking.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :target_user_id => @user.id).first_or_create
        @tracking.accessed_at = Time.now
        @tracking.save          
    end     
end
```

More usefull methods [here](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/)